# Silverlight/C# Canvas, his UIElements and Width

Tags: c#, silverlight, canvas, width, uielement

i created a class "Component", which will be added to the children of my canvas. After the adding, i want to position these components using for example:

```
comp.setValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 100d);
```

which works fine. After that the component will be added to canvas. 
Now my actual problem is to get the components actual width. I tried these things like

```
comp.Width;
comp.ActualWidth;
```

but they are 0 or NaN. In my understanding, this should be like that. Cause they have been added to the canvas, and should than obtain there specific sizes, or am i wrong with this?

Also, i added an OnClick-Event on those components, in which they write their ActualWidth on the console, and it works. But i want to get these informations directly after adding them..

Any ideas?

Greetings and stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework will trigger a [`measure and arrange cycle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) when you add children to a panel that is included in the `visual tree`.
After this layout pass, you can get the size by asking `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`.
Apparently the cycle is not completed (or yet to be triggered) when your code runs.
So what can you do? You can register an event handler on `FrameworkElement.SizeChanged` event and run your code inside the event handler.